# Can SQL 2008 Business Intelligence Studio SSIS packages run in SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis, business-intelligence

Is it possible to run an SSIS package created by SQL 2008 Business Intelligence Studio in a SQL 2005 environment? I'd rather not have to install SQL 2005 / VS 2005 in my development environment.

Comment: What do you mean by 'against' - run in a 2005 environment, or use 2005 as a data source?

Comment: Run in a 2005 environment (ie. with no 2008 installations required in production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 uses a different scripting environment called VSTA(Visual Studio Tools for Applications) whereas Sql Server 2005 uses VSA(Visual Studio for Applications). This talks a little more about VSTA here: [VSTA explanation](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/biz/SSIS_New_Features_in_SQL_Server_2008_Part5_p1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible - I run 2008 developed dtsx packages all the time on our 2005 box.

Comment: Will this include Script Tasks written in C# (which, as I understand it, was not supported in BIS 2005)?

Comment: No it will not, those you will have to convert to VB OR call the executables using the component (I forget the exact name for it but it can be done).